# Searching an array for a sequence of increasing integers

Tags: java, arrays, random, iteration

Here's the task:

Create a program that looks through a `200`-element array of randomly-generated integers with values between `25` and `225`. The program should look for `n` consecutive indices that hold non-decreasing values - for example:

`28, 57, 88, 153, 201` is considered a success

`28, 57, 32, 153, 201` is considered a failure.

Output should look something like:

```
An increasing consecutive run of 5 elements found at:

Index 41 contains 28
Index 42 contains 57
Index 43 contains 88
Index 44 contains 153
Index 45 contains 201
```

There are many ways to go about this task. **I've included a working step-by-step solution below.**

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: @azro Scroll down a bit, you'll find that I have answered this question myself and just wanted to share my knowledge. Sorry if this isn't needed here, I'm still quite new.

Comment: @AlexS if you already have working code, then there is another stack exchange site for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). If you want to post it there, however, please familiarize yourself with all of [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Posting working code here and asking for any improvements could be considered "too broad"

Comment: @PatrickParker I'm not exactly asking for improvements. I just noticed when posting an earlier topic that there was an option to answer your own question, and I thought "hey I know how to do this, might as well share - it might help someone else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

First, apply the given information (lower bound, upper bound, array size).

```
    int min = 25;
    int max = 225;
    int set[] = new int[200];
```

Set `n` to an arbitrary value. I will use 5 for demonstration purposes.

```
    int n = 5;
```

Create a `counter` variable to record the number of consecutive integers found. Further on we will add logic to reset the counter every time a sequence of numbers does not work.

```
    int counter = 0;
```

Start iterating. Create a `for` loop to fill the array with '200' elements between the specified bounds.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
        set[i] = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

Print out the contents of every index.

```
        System.out.println((i + 1) +") " + "Index " + i + " contains " + set[i]);
```

The first `if` statement: this will increment 'counter' by 1 every time a sequence fits the pattern, but resets it back to 0 when the comparison fails.

```
   if(i > 0){   
        if(set[i] >= set[i-1]){counter++;}
        else{counter = 0;}  
    }// End if
```

Now create a while statement that activates when the value of `counter` becomes equal to the value of `n`. This will print out the statement `An increasing consecutive run of 5 elements found at:` and then lead to a for loop.

```
    while(counter == n){

           System.out.println("An increasing consecutive run of " + n + " elements found at:");
```

Now set up this loop to simply print out the `n` lines that were successful.

```
    for(int j = i - n; j < i; j++){
        System.out.println("Index " + j + " contains " + set[j]);
    } //End for
```

Tell the code to stop running once all conditions are met.

```
       return;
```

Just close the while and for loops and the program is now complete.

```
        } //End while

    } //End for
```